# Can I edit xml using scala?

Tags: xml, scala

Given that i have a Node

```
var xml = XML.loadFile("some/file/here")
```

what can i do should i want to change the value of some element to a new value

That is,

```
...
<anElement>5</anElement>
...
```

to

```
...
<anElement>blooblahblahyah</anElement>
...
```

Apologies if this is a pretty silly question, i'm incredibly new to Scala and haven't found any definitive answer on xml editing.

Answer (score 3):

The [Node](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.xml.Node) is immutable and this makes editing it a bit tedious.
There are examples in the Scala [XML](http://www.scala-blogs.org/2008/01/meet-scalaxml-book-if-you-havent-yet.html) [book](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/xml-processing.html).

```
val foo = <foo><bar>1</bar><bar>2</bar></foo>
foo.copy (child = foo.child.map {case bar: scala.xml.Elem =>
  bar.copy (child = scala.xml.Text ((bar.text.toInt + 1).toString))})
```

`res0: scala.xml.Elem = <foo><bar>2</bar><bar>3</bar></foo>`

Comment: Also take a look at xml.transform: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.xml.transform.RewriteRule ; couple of examples: http://daily-scala.blogspot.ru/2009/12/xml-transformation-1.html